# JMeter - saving results to both CSV and XML

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

What I try to achieve is to get JMeter results in 2 formats, for the same test execution. CSV is the one I'm mostly interested in, unless there are failures - then I may need to use data which can be saved only to XML. I can't use XML for most occasions, due to misc reasons.

I was looking at **jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format** cfg entry, it doesn't seem to accept both as valid entry. I was also looking at JMeter code itself, it also clearly separates both options.

Did anyone invent a hack to get both JMeter outputs at the same time?

Solution for both standalone JMeter and jmeter-maven-plugin is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use JMeter Maven plugin, as per [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) the default output has to be XML.

If you need CSV output as well - just add [Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) listener. If you looking for CSV data to be in line with JMeter default CSV values configure it as follows:

[image: Simple Data Writer]