# jmeter maven csv jtl file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am running a few jmeter test plans together through jmeter-maven-plugin. I can see jtl files generated for each test plan. But the file content is in xml.  I tried modifying the pom file to have resultsFileFormat as csv but it still generates xml format jtl file. My current plugin config looks like this,

```
`<plugins>
 <plugin>
 <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
 <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                            <resultsFileFormat>csv</resultsFileFormat>
                            <propertiesJMeter>
                                <jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names>
                                <jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>
                                <jmeter.save.saveservice.label>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.label>
                                <jmeter.save.saveservice.time>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.time>
                            </propertiesJMeter>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

Please let me know how I could make the jtl content to be generated as csv.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737872/jmeter-saving-results-to-both-csv-and-xml

Comment: There was a bug in version 2.0.3 of the plugin that caused `< resultsFileFormat>` to be ignored.  It's fixed in 2.1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it a little bit differently, your settings should go to the `<propertiesUser>` section like:

```
<execution>
    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
    <phase>verify</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>jmeter</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <propertiesUser>
            <jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>csv</jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>
            <jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names>
            <jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>
            <jmeter.save.saveservice.label>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.label>
            <jmeter.save.saveservice.time>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.time>
        </propertiesUser>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Or alternatively create your own *user.properties* file with the following lines:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```

and drop it to "/src/test/jmeter" folder (where your .JMX files live)

As far as I'm aware, JMeter Maven plugin uses XML results file format by default and this configuration is applied via *jmeter.properties* file.

JMeter properties have the following overrides:

1. jmeter.properties
2. user.properties
3. command-line arguments

So you can override a property stored in *jmeter.properties* file via setting the same property in *user.properties* file and override the property originating from *user.properties* via `-J` command-line argument.

References:

- [Using Your Own Properties Files](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#using-your-own-properties-files)
- [Adding Additional Properties To](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#adding-additional-properties-to-propertiesuser)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)